# Djrill throwing 'TypeError' when send_mail method is used

Tags: django

I am currently trying to integrate mandrill into this Django-based website for emails. Djrill is the recommended package for Django and sits in place of the default SMTP/email backend, passing emails through to a Mandrill account.

When I try to test that this new backend is working by running this command:

```
send_mail('Test email', body, 'noreply@*********.com', [user.email], fail_silently=False)
```

It throws the following error: http://pastebin.ca/2239978

Can anybody point me to my mistake?

Comment: Put the traceback into your question and format it appropriately please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

As @DavidRobinson mentions in a comment, you are not getting a successful response from the mandrill API authentication call. You should double check your API key.

If that is correct, try using curl to post `{"key": <your api key>, "email": <your from email>}` to `MANDRILL_API_URL + "/users/verify-sender.json"` and see if you get a 200.

Something like this:

```
curl -d key=1234567890 -d email=noreply@mydomain.com http://mandrill.whatever.com/user/verify-sender.json
```

**Original answer:**

There is also an issue in Djrill that prevents a useful error message from propagating up.  That last line of the stack trace is the problem.

This is the entire `open` method taken from [the source](https://github.com/brack3t/Djrill/blob/master/djrill/mail/backends/djrill.py):

```
def open(self, sender):
    """
    """
    self.connection = None

    valid_sender = requests.post(
        self.api_verify, data={"key": self.api_key, "email": sender})

    if valid_sender.status_code == 200:
        data = json.loads(valid_sender.content)
        if data["is_enabled"]:
            self.connection = True
            return True
    else:
        if not self.fail_silently:
            raise
```

See how it just says `raise` without an exception argument? That syntax is only allowed inside an `except` block, and raises the exception currently being handled.  It doesn't work outside an `except` block.

[An open issue](https://github.com/brack3t/Djrill/issues/1) in Djrill mentions a send failure and links a fork that supposedly fixes it.  I suspect Djrill isn't well supported and you might try that fork or another solution entirely.

Comment: I found the same thing, but even if this is fixed, this doesn't fix  the underlying issue the user is having, which is the status code (fixing it will just cause a different exception to be thrown!)

Comment: Ah, good point. Tunnel vision. I suppose it is an api permission problem and it's time for curl debugging.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, @dokkaebi. Do you think it would be an easy fix?

Comment: I have checked the API logs on the Mandrill website and it shows that my server is pinging the API correctly. Can you give me an example of how to 'curl' an API request?